# @parcel/transformer-sass: Undefined mixin

Tags: sass, scss-mixins, parcel

I'm seeing this error when I try to run parcel:

`@parcel/transformer-sass: Undefined mixin.`

```
ℹ Server running at http://localhost:1234
× Build failed.
@parcel/transformer-sass: Undefined mixin.
   ╷
53 │       @include button-variant($background, $border);
   │       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  srcstylesbootstrap_mixins.scss 53:7   generate-buttons()
  srcstylesbootstrap_helpers.scss 23:1  @import
  srcstylesbootstrapbootstrap.scss 5:9  @import
  srcstylesbootstrap.scss 1:9            root stylesheet
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the mixin wasn't being imported in the file that was trying to reference it. So the fix was to add the appropriate import statement:

```
@import './_mixins.scss';
```

Answer (score 0):

As @james-gentes' answer mentions, you need to import the mixin. However, the `@import` approach is being deprecated in favor of using `@use` see the [sass documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import)

You should import it like this:

```
@use './_mixins.scss';
```